# How do I turn a c# attribute into a text content?

Tags: c#, attributes, registry, metadata

I have a solution with several C# class libraries that are plugins in a larger system. This system registers its plugins in Windows' registry. What I would like to do is describe the registry keys in a way that can be extracted from the compiled DLLS and then put into a text (.reg) file, preferably as part of the build process.

Is there a predefined attribute for this type of metadata? And is there a command line tool or MSBuild task that can extract them?

Comment: Well you can easily create your own attribute... and it's easy to load an assembly and extract attributes using reflection. I suggest you try that, and ask a specific question if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This seemed like a "re-inventing the wheel" kind of question, so I wanted to make sure I hadn't missed something in the framework before I rolled my own solution.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a *particularly* common thing to want to do... embedding data in attributes, sure - but not specifically registry keys, wanting to then create a `.reg` file with them. I'm not saying no-one else has ever wanted that, but I don't think it's a sufficiently common requirement that you should expect to find an out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine this attribute

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class,
                   AllowMultiple = true)  // Multiuse attribute.]
public class RegistryKey : System.Attribute
{
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public string Type {get; private set;}
    public string Data {get; private set;}

    public RegistryKey(string name, string type, string data)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

Consume it with reflection like this

```
var attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MahClass));
foreach (var attr in attrs)
{
    if (attr is RegistryKey)
    {
        var name = attr.Name;
        ...
    }
}
```